# Does changing the HardwareID of PCI in Registry affect anything?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

I wanted to know if changing the following Registry entry will affect the behaviour of my PC:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\PCI[..]\HardwareID
```

If I changed this, would there be any "side"-effects (like, would Windows shut down)?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Hacking the registry is a sure way to cause all sorts of problems if you are not well versed on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't do it. This is internal info used by the PlugPlay service to enumerate devices in our system. If you change it, it would no longer match physical hardware.

Comment: Might cause windows to invalidate the installed product key also.

Comment: @Moab nope, product key is stored elsewhere